# Integration w. r. t. counting measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm learning about measure theory, specifically integration w.r.t. counting measure, and need help to verify my understanding of this new notion through two exercises.

> (1) Let $(\mathbb{N},\scr{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$ be a measure space where  $\mu$ is the counting measure. Let $E = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. Find $\int_E d\mu.$

If I understand this notion correctly, integrating w.r.t. counting measure is just summation, that is

$$\int_{\mathbb{N}} f\,\text{d}\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n).$$

Since we are integrating the constant function $f(k) = 1$ it would seem that

$$\int_E d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^5 f(n) = 5.$$

> $(2)$ Let $\mu$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$ and $f(k) = 2k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $E = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. Find $\int_E f \, d\mu$.

By the same previous argument we have

$$\int_E f(k) \, d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^5 f(k) =2 \times 1 + 2 \times 2  + \ldots + 2 \times 5 =  30.$$

Is my work/understanding of integration w.r.t. to counting measure correct?

Comment: You are correct. You didn't write the second exercise explicitly, however.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Thanks. I have edited my original question so others can follow more easily.